# Параллельное выполнение команд в bash

Tags: bash, grep

Есть большое количество текстовых файлов расположенных в нескольких подкаталогах каталога data.
Есть текстовый файл содержащий ~200 строк.
Задача найти все строки из этого файла в файлах расположенных в каталоге data.
Вот такая конструкция решает вопрос, но ужасно медленно (по 10 минут на каждую строку, а их порядка 200)

```
#! /bin/bash/
readarray -t LINES < file.lst
    for i in "${!LINES[@]}"; do
    grep -r -i "${LINES[i]}" /home/data/
    echo "${LINES[i]}" 
done
```

Попытка добавить `&` в конеце строки с `grep`

```
#! /bin/bash/
readarray -t LINES < file.lst
    for i in "${!LINES[@]}"; do
    grep -r -i "${LINES[i]}" /home/data/ &
    echo "${LINES[i]}" 
done
```

для запуска всех процессов параллельно приводит к некорректной работе скрипта.

Подскажите, как ускорить этот процесс?

Comment: Может проще `grep -f file.lst -r -i /home/data`?

Comment: И если задача найти именно строки, то может надо использовать флаги -F и -x и не нужен -i.

Comment: По сути вам надо сохдать хеш-массив всех строк всех файлов. Дальше плёвое дело всё это сравнить по хешам. Если самому не хочется с этим заморачиваться, то можно использовать... (сюрприз, сюрприз!) Git. Загрузите все ваши файлы в Git, и воспользуйтесь `git grep ...` вместо вот этого медленного монстра. (Вместо ваших O(n^2) вы получите O(nlogn) по скорости)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, не проще. Обычный `grep` для такой задачи сам по себе плох, а тут ещё и размножение процессов до бесконечности — у вас файловые дескрипторы быстрее закончатся.

Comment: @0andriy с чего бы? Греп читает файлы по очереди, так что дескрипторов хватит. Если у автора было 10 минут на один проход по всем файлам, то подозреваю, что тут будут те же 10 минут на всё

Comment: С хеш-массивом идея интересная, попробую, спасибо. Но придётся создавать самому, у меня файлов на 40+ Гб. Ну, а пока искал решение, сделал напролом. Разбил текстовый файл на 12 частей, скопировал весь каталог data на отдельный диск и запустил 12 терминалов со своим монстром. 10 часов и работа закончена. Тут как раз тот случай, когда нужен результат. Но задача будет повторятся, поэтому пойду экспериментировать с хешем. Всем спасибо!